# Convert Histogram from frequency of string length to percentage

Tags: plotting, graphics, histograms

I have the histogram:

```
dataPnJ = StringLength[StringSplit[ExampleData[{"Text", "PrideAndPrejudice"}]]];
Histogram[dataPnJ]
```

I am trying to make the histogram show what percentage of the total pool is the string length representing. So like if 30% of the text is 3 letter words the bin will be labeled 3 and will go up to 30%.

Answer (score 5):

```
Histogram[dataPnJ, {1}, "Probability", 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, {#, PercentForm @ #} & /@ Range[0, .5, .1]}, 
 LabelingFunction -> (Placed[ PercentForm @ #, Tooltip] &)]
```

[image]

You can also use `HistogramList` to get a list of bar heights and use it with `BarChart`:

```
heights = HistogramList[dataPnJ, {1}, "Probability"][[2]];

BarChart[Labeled[#, Rotate[PercentForm[#, {5, 3}], 90 Degree], Above] & /@ heights, 
 BarSpacing -> 0, 
 ChartLabels -> Range[Length @ heights], 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, {#, PercentForm @ #} & /@ Range[0, .5, .1]}, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Riffing off of [@kglr's excellent answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/209822/27951), we can go a little further and fulfill all your requirements regarding labeling of the bars within `Histogram`, without having to build our own `BarChart`:

```
dataPnJ = StringLength[StringSplit[ExampleData[{"Text", "PrideAndPrejudice"}]]];

Histogram[
 dataPnJ, {1}, "Probability",
 Ticks -> {Range[20], {#, PercentForm@#} & /@ Range[0, .5, .1]}, 
 LabelingFunction -> (Placed[
     Rotate[PercentForm@Round[#, 0.001], 90 Degree], Above
   ] &)
]
```

[image: modified histogram using ticks as bar labels and percentages as bar readouts]